# Передача BufferedImage по сети Java

Tags: java, сокет

Цель состоит в том, чтобы передать изображение в формате BufferedImage по сети.
Сервер и клиент уже созданы, строку передают, а как передать изображение?

Comment: Перегнать картинку в массив байтов, после чего отослать через сокет длину массива и следом сам массив.

Comment: А как объект BufferedImage конвертировать в byte[]?

Comment: Посмотрите на эти вопросы: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157023/how-can-i-convert-bufferedimage-to-byte, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414259/java-bufferedimage-to-byte-array-and-back, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247123/java-convert-bufferedimage-to-byte-without-writing-to-disk.

Comment: а передавать нужно по одному байту или можно как-то массивом? Просто у меня это все в таймере и если делать циклом, то может не влезть по времени...